# Java Semaphore Await Idleness impact on other threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

Assuming I'm managing my threadpools so there's no starvation...

when I use a semaphore or another synchronizer, and the semaphore causes a thread to wait until the specified event happens (e.g. the semaphore releases a token), can that awaiting thread (which is doing nothing) still be competing for processor resources against active threads? Or does it take the backseat resource-wise until the semaphore releases a token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Javadoc for `Semaphore.acquire`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#acquire%28%29) is pretty explicit about this:

> If no permit is available then the current thread becomes **disabled for
>   thread scheduling purposes** and **lies dormant** until one of two things
>   happens: [...]

So yes, the waiting thread takes the backseat resource-wise until a permit becomes available.

Answer (score 1):

The waiting thread is put to sleep. It does not eat any processor time, i.e., it does not perform busy waiting while polling for the waiting condition to be true. It is just not considered by the scheduler. The semaphore will explicitly wake up the thread once it is free again.